# Перегрузка операторов. Сложение умножение и вычитание

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Вроде бы понимаю что происходит, но не понимаю почему ничего не работает

operator_overload.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Path {
    int km, mm, m;
public:
    Path();
    Path(int akm, int am, int amm);
    ~Path();
    int getkm() const;
    int getm() const;
    int getmm() const;
    void setkm(const int akm);
    void setm(const int am);
    void setmm(const int amm);
    int calculate_Path() const;
    Path& operator+ (const Path& right) const;
    Path& operator- (const Path& right) const;
    Path& operator* (int a) const;
    Path& operator =(const Path& obj);
};
```

operator_overload.cpp

```
#include "operator_overload.h"

Path::Path() {};
Path::~Path() {};
Path::Path(int akm, int am, int amm) {
    km = akm;
    m = am;
    mm = amm;
}
int Path::getkm() const {
    return this->km;
}
int Path::getm() const {
    return this->m;
}
int Path::getmm() const {
    return this->mm;
}
void Path::setkm(const int akm) {
    km = akm;
}
void Path::setm(const int am) {
    m = am;
}
void Path::setmm(const int amm) {
    mm = amm;
}
int Path::calculate_Path() const {
    return this->getkm() + this->getm() + this->getmm();
}
Path& Path::operator+(const Path& right) { 
    return Path(calculate_Path() + right.calculate_Path());
}
```

Выдает ошибку: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в части кода :

```
Path Path::operator+(const Path& right) { 
    return Path(calculate_Path() + right.calculate_Path());
}
```

Comment: Вы уж решите, возвращаете ли вы ссылку или значение `Path`. Сразу - ссылка на временный объект - большая ошибка...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ

operator_overload.cpp

```
#include "operator_overload.h"

Path::Path() {}
Path::Path(const Path& obj) {
    setkm(obj.getkm());
    setm(obj.getm());
    setmm(obj.getmm());
}
Path::Path(int akm, int am, int amm) : km(akm), m(am), mm(amm) {}
// \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/
Path::Path(int s) {
    setkm(s);
    setm(s);
    setmm(s);
}
// /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\
Path::~Path() {}
int Path::getkm() const {
    return this->km;
}
int Path::getm() const {
    return this->m;
}
int Path::getmm() const {
    return this->mm;
}
void Path::setkm(const int akm) {
    km = akm;
}
void Path::setm(const int am) {
    m = am;
}
void Path::setmm(const int amm) {
    mm = amm;
}
int Path::calculate_Path() const {
    return this->getkm() + this->getm() + this->getmm();
}
int Path::subtract_Path() const {
    return this->getkm() - this->getm() - this->getmm();
}
Path Path::operator+(const Path& right) const { 
    return Path(calculate_Path() + right.calculate_Path());
}
Path Path::operator-(const Path & right) const {
    return Path(subtract_Path() - right.subtract_Path());
}
```